# PHP multiplication decimals

Tags: php, decimal, multiplication

I have a strange bug when multiplying decimals.  When I multiply a decimal such as 2.1 by a number such as 2 (to get the product 4.2), PHP displays them identically, and, on comparison, shows them as equal.  But when I multiply 2.1 by 7 (14.7), though PHP still displays them as equal, upon comparison it declares the products unequal.

Here's code illustrating the issue (note what PHP returns):

```
$num_1 = 4.2;
$num_2 = 2.1*2;
if($num_1 == $num_2){
  $eq = "Equal";
}else{
  $eq = "Unequal";
}
echo $num_1.", ".$num_2.", ".$eq."<br>";
// Returns  4.2, 4.2, Equal

$num_1 = 14.7;
$num_2 = 2.1*7;
if($num_1 == $num_2){
  $eq = "Equal";
}else{
  $eq = "Unequal";
}
echo $num_1.", ".$num_2.", ".$eq."<br>";
// Returns  14.7, 14.7, Unequal
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the fun of [floating point arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that some floating point numbers can't be represented accurately. If you need to compare them, or a higher level of precision, use [bcmul](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php)

```
$num_1 = 14.7;
$num_2 = bcmul(2.1, 7, 1);
if((string)$num_1 == $num_2){
  $eq = "Equal";
}else{
  $eq = "Unequal";
}
echo $num_1.", ".$num_2.", ".$eq."<br>";
```

Comment: Assuming php (on *nix) was compiled with `--enable-bcmath`.

Comment: I think this is probably the best formal way to go, thanks.  For reasons I won't go into, I need to have a numeric value, not a string, so I'm actually using the round solution suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `round()`.

```
$num_1 = round(14.7, 2);
$num_2 = round(2.1 * 7, 2);
echo ($num_1 == $num_2) ? 'equal' : 'uequal';
```

Now notice the result here what exactly occurred.

```
$num_1 = 14.7;
$num_2 = 2.1 * 7;
echo abs($num_1-$num_2); //Output: 1.7763568394003E-15
```

Answer (score -1):

This is PHP, bro!
Just convert your floats to strings and compare them...

```
$num_1 = 14.7;
$num_2 = 2.1*7;
if((string) $num_1 == (string) $num_2){
  $eq = "Equal";
}else{
  $eq = "Unequal";
}
echo $num_1.", ".$num_2.", ".$eq."<br>";
```

Or use that `bcmul` as shown above...